# Magento 2 - Name Prefix has first dropdown empty

Tags: magento2, customer

I have a problem with the prefix field.

I have set it to be optional and I added two values in "Prefix Dropdown Options": Mr;Mrs.

Everything it's correct except from the first option of the generated select, which is empty.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="select select__wrapper">
  <select class="select" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    value: value,
    optionsCaption: caption,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label',
    optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) {
        if (item &amp;&amp; item.disabled) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {attr: {disabled: true}}, item);
        }
    }" name="prefix" id="SO7RWP3" aria-invalid="false">
    <option data-title="" value=" "></option>
    <option data-title="Mr" value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option data-title="Mrs" value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to add a translation for the first option like "Select a prefix"?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I got what You want, but it seems that its enough to change

```
<option data-title="" value=" "></option>
```

to

```
<option data-title="" value=" ">Select a prefix</option>
```

.

EDIT:
In that case look into:

```
src/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Options.php
```

there is function **getNameSuffixOptions** that calls  **prepareNamePrefixSuffixOptions** there is :

```
$result = array_merge([' ' => ' '], $result);
```

that create empty value.
Override getNameSuffixOptions function or use di after, to change this value to `Select a prefix`.

Comment: The problem is that the select is automatically created somehow..I add the dropdown values from the admin panel...

Comment: i just edit my post

Comment: That's great! In order to override that function can I copy/paste the entire file in app/frontend/_THEME_/Default/Magento_Customer/Model/Options.php and make my changes there?

Comment: noooo. Use di.xml. Its like basic magento stuff https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html or https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: I will have to investigate on it but you helped me getting in the right path! Thanks

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Applying for checkout file is in deferent module

Override using preference in di.xml and

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/Model/Options.php
```

apply logic in line 142-150

```
$i=0; 
foreach ($options as $value) {
        $value = $this->escaper->escapeHtml(trim($value));
        if($i===0) {
            $result[' '] = ' ';
        }
        $result[$value] = $value;
        $i++;
    }
```

It works fine for me!!

Happy Coding!!